# php7 and mysql extension

Tags: php, mysql

After launching the following code...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect()
?>
```

I have `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()` in log.

The first thing that comes in mind is to do `sudo apt-get install php-mysql` but it outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-mysql is already the newest version
```

after that I did `dpkg --list | grep mysql` and it said that `php-mysql` and `php7.0-mysql` are installed.

What is wrong here?

**PS.** PHP version is `7.0.8`.

Answer (score 3):

> Call to undefined function mysql_connect

The `mysql_` library was deprecated years ago. It has been removed entirely in PHP 7.

Use a modern replacement such as PDO or `mysqli_`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `mysqli_*` functions, not `mysql_*`.

Comment: You're trying to say that there's no `mysql_*` functions in `PHP7`?

Comment: @Eugeny89 http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: @Eugeny89 if you're switching to `mysqli_*` you should probably use the `mysqli` class with parameterized queries.